# Want to move a file to a folder in Shell Script but whilst doing so have a version number appended to it

Tags: shell, append, version, mv

The script will move the file (in the `RecycleBin`) but I want the version number appended to it. The version number cosists of: current month, date, year, hour, minute and second:

So the file should look something like this:

`file.081213.191134` - Where the file is deleted on Aug 12th, 2013, 19:11:34.

Not sure what kind of structure I should use for this?

Want to keep it as simple as possible

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
mv $file /path/to/RecycleBin/$file.`date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"`
```

As the command `date` shows:

```
$ date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S"
20130403.152826
```

Comment: Now it shows it like `20130403.152826` (YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS). If you want it `130403.152826` (YYMMDD.HHMMSS, not first two digits of the year), write `date +"%y%m%d.%H%M%S"`